# Should I reply to a comment that is incorrect?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, best-practices

I recently encountered a comment from a question's OP that looked like this:

> I really don't like having my posts edited but I let it go this time because I know my post was poorly written. @Nai45, thank you for making my post more clear.

after I edited their post to make it on-topic.

Their reply comment is not rude or anything worthy of being flagged, but the user makes the incorrect statement of:

> I really don't like having my posts edited but I let it go this time

because the OP doesn't get to control when their post is edited.

As a general rule for comments like these, what should I do?

I could

**a) respond back with something like this:**

> @__user You're very welcome! Please also note that you can not control when your posts are edited or who they are edited by. Editing is a tool that is available to everybody in order to improve posts.

But I just fear that this action will spur a lengthy discussion in comments which I would like to avoid.

**b) not respond:**

This makes sense, but I also don't what the user to walk away thinking that they get to pick and choose when their posts are edited.

**c) some other option:**

Such as flagging (which is think is unnecessary in this scenario) or bringing it up on the said site's meta (which also seems unnecessary).

Comment: Lean towards b) unless maybe they make more comments that need correction. or a) if it's a gross mistake. If you need to correct everybody that's wrong in comments ever [you'd never go to bed](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: Wait. You mean its not the way of things to keep people awake with my typoes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just flag as no longer needed and move on. You have done your part and not much good comes of arguing with folks(which will inevitably happen), especially with that attitude.

Comment: There is also the possibility that the user doesn’t know too much about the site, in which case ignoring it and flagging it would be doing that user a disservice.

Comment: Possibly but considering the dynamic - that would lead to more friction. Better someone else pick it up